# Error in import deepface to use be used in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: tensorflow

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-9992a767273a> in <module>
----> 1 from deepface import DeepFace

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\deepface\DeepFace.py in <module>
      9 import pickle
     10 
---> 11 from deepface.basemodels import VGGFace, OpenFace, Facenet, FbDeepFace, DeepID, DlibWrapper, ArcFace, Boosting
     12 from deepface.extendedmodels import Age, Gender, Race, Emotion
     13 from deepface.commons import functions, realtime, distance as dst

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\deepface\basemodels\VGGFace.py in <module>
      3 import gdown
      4 
----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 tf_version = int(tf.__version__.split(".")[0])
      7 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     37 # go/tf-wildcard-import
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
---> 39 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
     40 
     41 from tensorflow.python.eager import context

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: Please decorate your error with your goal, what you expect, link to the asset you try to get running and what action gave this error

Comment: Seems your tensorflow installation is not completed yet.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @johncasey
Tensorflow installation not completed.

Follow the steps to install TEnsorflow

```
Below are the instructions to install Tensorflow 2.0 using PIP

#Install tensorflow using pip virtual env 
$pip install virtualenv
$virtualenv tf   # tf is virtual env name
$source tf/bin/activate
tf $ pip install tensorflow
tf $ python
>>import tensorflow as tf
>>tf.__version__
2.5.0
```

Make sure your system meets all the software requirements mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements).